# I'm trying to remove a group of columns from a dataset using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[All of the variables to remove starts with 'P' followed by some integer(for example P101, P102, P201 etc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFw7X.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
filtered_column=df.filter(regex=r'^p',axis=1).columns.values
df=df.drop(filtered_column, axis=1)
```

As you didn't provide a sample data I created this my self.

Input:

```
   p101  p102  p103  q21  qw32  kwp
0    68    17    54   67    93   36
1    32    22    56   69    38    6
2    58    48    89   68    60   79
3    64    14    63   53     7   86
4    67    94    47   94    73   53
5    96    34    87   83    12   18
6    15    62    47    4    22   53
7     3    63    12   24    68   14
8    22    32    17   45    96   44
9    19    48    37   75    53   22
```

Output:

```
   q21  qw32  kwp
0   67    93   36
1   69    38    6
2   68    60   79
3   53     7   86
4   94    73   53
5   83    12   18
6    4    22   53
7   24    68   14
8   45    96   44
9   75    53   22
```

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. But please make sure next time you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of column names like this

`col_names = [col for col in df.columns if col[0]=='P']`

or any other similar logic if you want and then use df.drop() as

`new_df = df.drop(col_names, axis=1)`

Note : If you have any other column name starting with P this logic will delete that too, so do see to that.

Comment: I do have columns that start with 'P' but are not followed by an integer like for example 'PIT501', and such columns shouldn't get deleted.